# Read delta table in spark with NOT NULL constraint

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, schema, databricks, delta-lake

I am reading a delta table like this

```py
df = (spark
  .read
  .format("delta")
  .load("/path/to/foo/table")
  .select("Foo_ID", "Bar")
)
```

now when I look at the DataFrame schema, spark has somehow incorrectly inferred nullability:

```
>>> df.schema
...
StructType([StructField('Foo_ID', LongType(), True), StructField('Bar', TimestampType(), True)])
```

I know the values should not be null and I want the schema to reflect that by imposing a not null constraint on the columns. In case I try to load a table that actually does contain a null I want to see a big fat error message, rather than silently switching. Is there a clean way to do this? I came up with the following workaround, but it doesn't feel very nice:

```
my_schema = StructType([StructField('Foo_ID', LongType(), False), StructField('Bar', TimestampType(), False)])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=my_schema)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table was created with the constraint, then Spark will infer nullability:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta/table` (
  foo_id LONG NOT NULL,
  bar TIMESTAMP
) USING DELTA;

val df = spark.read.load("/tmp/delta/table")
df.printSchema

root
 |-- foo_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Apparently it wasn't. But you can always change it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta/table` (
  foo_id LONG,
  bar TIMESTAMP
) USING DELTA;

ALTER TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta/table` CHANGE COLUMN foo_id foo_id LONG NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta/table` CHANGE COLUMN bar bar TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;

val df = spark.read.load("/tmp/delta/table")
df.printSchema

root
 |-- foo_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

Or, if you don't want or cannot change it, then what you came up with is not a workaround, it is a solution. You just explicitly specify a schema you want to read data with.

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought maybe there could a way to inform the loading procedure about the schema more directly. Like you can for example do `spark.read.format('csv').schema(my_schema)` but this is not supported for the delta format. I guess changing the underlying table constraints, as you suggest, is the cleanest way.